# Using ReSharper can you select a rule to ensure that the returned value is either a literal or a variable for C#

Tags: c#, resharper, code-inspection

This question is about if ReSharper supports such a thing and how to turn such a rule check on.  This is not a question about a particular coding style or standard choice or merit.

I am trying to automate checking for (and ideally replacement) of various C# return code patterns.  In particular I wish to detect the following and have resharper make a hint/suggestion

```
return SomeFunc(someArgs);
return condition ? litteralA : litteralB;
return someObject.SomeFunction();
```

The following do not need to be highlighted (but I would accept them being picked up as innocent bystanders)

```
return someObject.SomePropertyOrField;
```

The following must not be falsely detected/highlighted (ideally ReSharper would do the simple transformation if possible)

```
var someVal = SomeFunc(someArgs);
return someVal;

var result = condition ? litteralA : litteralB;
return result;

var state = someObject.SomeFunction();
return state;

return SomeClass.SomeConst;
return true;
return 0;
return LocalConst;
```

*Can the latest release of ReSharper do this and if so how can I configure it to do it*

I cannot see how I would do it from [the feature list](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html) or by looking through the inspection options of a trial version of ReSharper; but I don't know what such a rule would be called if it was in fact there.  If it is in fact possible then I would like to know before having to write my code inspection utility.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: As much as I love SO for its wide and deep knowledge, surely https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us would be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: @DavidG Typically people like to do that for code inspection during debugging.

Comment: @juharr Which you will have in the consumer of the function

Comment: Custom inspection patterns might be what you want: Options => Code Inspection => Custom Patterns. Otherwise a custom Roslyn analzer rule would be an alternative.

Comment: Here's a link to a page about how to create custom rules in R# https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html

Comment: @DavidG I don't agree with the practice, but I've worked with people that still do it.

Comment: This is to fix up an old existing code base (that I didn't write) against a coding standard that has been imposed upon me (and have no say in).  I can either try and find them with some sort of grep and fix them up manually, use some sort of glorified sed, or find a tool that will do a better job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to go into *why* you want this; I'm sure you have a reason (which would be awesome if you share with the rest of us), but here's one solution:

You can use `Custom Patterns` (Options | Code Inspection | Custom Patterns) like this:

[image: ReSharper Custom Patterns]

See more information here: [ReSharper - Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html)

Comment: The Stack Exchange question editor repeatedly battered me with "This question looks like it is based on opinion and will be closed as inappropriate", so I was actively avoiding opinion